# Why is my output file blank?

Tags: java, input

I wrote some code to take an input file textfile.txt and output the number of lines it contains to a text file outputtextfile.txt, but the output is blank.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException
{       
    String inputFileName = "textfile.txt";

    printFileStats(inputFileName);
}
public static void printFileStats(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    String outputFileName = "outputtextfile.txt";
    File inputFile = new File(fileName);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);

    int lines = 0;
    int words = 0;
    int letters = 0;

    while(in.hasNextLine())
    {
        lines++;
    }
    out.print(lines);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the input from the `Scanner` instance to allow the `while` loop to complete

```
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
   in.nextLine(); // add this
   lines++;
}
```

In addition close the `PrintWriter`

```
out.close();
```

Comment: Still blank. I've never written code like this so don't be surprised if something wrong is glaringly obvious.

Comment: You're not consuming the input from the `Scanner`. See above

Answer (score 0):

Check out the PrintWriter docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html

You need to flush() the output stream in order to write because the PrintWriter doesn't do it automatically.

Also, you should be freeing up the resources by calling close() on the PrintWriter once you are done with it!